# Query firestore by date

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to query firestore by date getting only one result based on the current year, month and day.

In my collection, Im storing timestamp objects like so.
[image]

my query:

```dart
Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime.now());
    var date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
        timestamp.millisecondsSinceEpoch,
        isUtc: true);
    var tomorrow = date.add(Duration(days: 1));
    var yesterday = date.subtract(Duration(days: 1));

    await _firebaseFirestore
        .collection('users')
        .doc(_user.uid)
        .collection('foods')
        .where("createdAt",
            isGreaterThan:
                DateTime(yesterday.year, yesterday.month, yesterday.day, 0))
        .where("createdAt",
            isLessThan:
                DateTime(tomorrow.year, tomorrow.month, tomorrow.day, 0))
        .get()
```

I have three records (1) from yesterday, (1) from today and (1) from tomorrow.

Im getting the day yesterday and the today's record and Im not sure why.

I also tried to remove the two `where` clauses and instead do one with `isEqualTo`  but that gets me no results.

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```dart
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
DateTime startOfDay = DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day);
DateTime startOfNextDay = startOfDay.add(Duration(days: 1));

await _firebaseFirestore
        .collection('users')
        .doc(_user.uid)
        .collection('foods')
        .where("createdAt", isGreaterThan: startOfDay)
        .where("createdAt", isLessThan: startOfNextDay)
        .orderBy("createdAt", "asc")
        .limit(1)
        .get()
```

You will get back a QuerySnapshot and will want to extract the 1 record from the `.docs` array (or via `.forEach()`).  There might not be any documents if there are no docs for that given period.

Of course rather than using `DateTime.now()`, you could pass in values for YEAR, MONTH and DAY to be used in the calculation of `startOfDay`.

Note, I'm not sure why you were doing:

```dart
Timestamp timestamp = Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime.now());
var date = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
              timestamp.millisecondsSinceEpoch,
              isUtc: true);
```

instead of just doing:

```dart
var date = DateTime.now();
```

Comment: Thank you Greg ! Assuming only one record exist for today. the `oderBy` and `limit` are not really necessary right ? or is there any particular reason why you added those to the query ?

Comment: If you can guarantee that only 1 doc per day, then you are good without them.  Also, you might consider storing the date as a string and querying on that, rather than messing around with Timestamps.  If your dates are all stored as `yyyy-mm-dd` then that would make query matches a lot easier.  You could even consider storing the date as 3 separate fields:  `year` , `month`, and `day`.  Or 3 fields inside of an object: `{ year, month, day }`